# What is this line, how did I do and how do I delete it?

Tags: qgis

I have taken up QGIS 2.18 today and have created a map of sales territories but in doing so have somehow put a line across England. If I hide all the layers it remains in place, I can find no way of selecting it and have no idea what it is. My main aim is to remove it but any extra information (how, what, purpose etc.) would be welcome too.
[image]

Comment: Did you edit any layer in project? Or did you use measuring tool etc.? Did you try save and reopen QGIS project? If its not a part of any layer, it looks like you something draw and unfinish.

Comment: @OtoKaláb I think this could be the only possible explanation and maybe you should post it as an answer.

Comment: What happens when you add this data to a new Qgis Map Document? In the past, I've had this appear only in a particlur map, but it was not actually added to the data.

Comment: Thank you Oto and mgri. Oto - you're suggestion must be correct as I had saved the project and walked away in frustration but opening it now - the line has gone. I appreciate you taking the time to think about such a newbie question :)

Answer (score 0):

Select and press ctrl + x possibly.